# How do you pronounce $\&$ in combinatorial game theory!

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, pronunciation

I have watched Owen Maitzen’s video on combinatorial game theory, and I saw this equation:

$\bf{hi} + \bf{oof} = \bf{hot} \, \rm{\&} \, \bf{oof}$

Owen Maitzen pronounced it 'hi plus oof equals hot and oof'. But using 'and' for it can be confusing. So how else can I pronounce this symbol in combinatorial game theory?

Some options are:

1. 'hi plus oof equals hot ampersand oof'
2. 'hi plus oof equals hot, offside oof'
3. 'hi plus oof equals a game with onside hot and offside oof'
4. 'hi plus oof has onside hot and offside oof'

But they are all quite verbose. So how should I pronounce this $\&$?

Comment: You could try **"op-and"** which could be like "operation and". Alternative : **"and-op"** == "and operation". Either way , there is Easy Disambiguation with "and" , while being not too verbose !!

Comment: If you don't want to say just "and", you could say "amp"